# Using web.archive.org to recover website data

Tags: mediawiki

I had a mediawiki website and there were some images which were removed because of useless. Later all images were deleted but links to them were saved in the form like:

```
http://web.com/images/*/*.jpg
```

I've tried to put links to the from on https://archive.org/web/
Then I receive my images on the link:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/*some date*/http://web.com/images/*/*.jpg
```

How can I get all images contained in list.txt file which were saved with webarchive?

My idea is to use curl because of complex POST and GET queries but I can't understand how to make it work with webarchive.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [warrick](https://code.google.com/p/warrick/) to recover lost web sites. It will not only use archive.org, but Google cache and several other sources to attempt to recover the data.

Comment: It didn't work in my case. Here an example:
The problem is that when I fill form at https://archive.org/web/ with my url and press browse history - everything works well.
URL: http://lurkmore.so/images/0/00/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F-3.png

But when I try to recover it with warrick, i'm in stuck:
perl ~/warrick/warrick.pl http://lurkmore.so/images/0/00/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D1%8F-3.png -D "/images_404_18052014" -nv -xc -nc
Result - no image